# Try Ubuntu 16.04 fails on 256 GB Kingston SSD with 2 1TB scsi in Raid 1

Tags: ssd, raid

I have a new PC with the specs as indicated below. I am ready to do a clean install of UBUNTU, but wanted to make sure it was compatible with my hardware first, so I selected "Try Ubuntu".  I am using the latest download 16.04.1 as of yesterday. The symptom is a lot of churning of the DVD drive and ending with a blank screen.

The configuration now is Windows 10 (ugh) with the OS installed on the SSD and all my documents, pictures etc on the 1TB raid 1.

Perhaps I can't test this in "Try Ubuntu" mode?  If not are these hardware specs supported?

Thanks

Mike

**PROCESSOR**
3.60 gigahertz Intel Core i7-4790
256 kilobyte primary memory cache
1024 kilobyte secondary memory cache
8192 kilobyte tertiary memory cache
64-bit ready
Multi-core (4 total)

**Main Circuit Board**
Board: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. H87M-E Rev X.0x
Serial Number: 151056075000296
Bus Clock: 100 megahertz
UEFI: American Megatrends Inc. 2201 06/18/2015

**DRIVES**
1239.67 Gigabytes Usable Hard Drive Capacity
651.42 Gigabytes Hard Drive Free Space

HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GH24NSC0 SCSI CdRom Device [Optical drive]

Intel Raid 1 Volume SCSI Disk Device (1000.19 GB) -- drive 1, s/n Volume1, SMART Status: Healthy
KINGSTON SV300S37A240G [Hard drive] (240.06 GB) -- drive 0, s/n 50026B775802D685, rev 603ABBF0, SMART Status: Healthy

**DISPLAY ADAPTER**
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 [Display adapter]
Samsung S27D360 [Monitor] (27.2"vis, s/n 031HHCPF800898, August 2014) 
Hyper-threaded (8 total)

Comment: Try hitting the F6 key at Ubuntu Live DVD and selecting `nomodeset` and see if that helps. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks @heynnema.  I tried that and the desktop does appear and I can access my raid drives.  The resolution is very poor.  Do the results of the nomodeset boot mean that the video driver isn't available for the video card installed, or are there third party drivers that do not load on "Try Ubuntu" that will load on a real install?

Comment: Good. Progress! See my answer below, for complete details. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Boot the Ubuntu Live DVD. Watch at the bottom of the window for some function key modifiers. When you see them, hit `F6` and select `nomodeset`, and continue trying Ubuntu. Nomodeset compensates for some video cards that don't have the proper drivers installed (yet).

Regarding installation, I'd recommend keeping Windows 10 on your SSD. You'll never know when you'll need it (ie: for BIOS updates, etc.). Depending on how large the Windows partition is, you may wish to decrease its size if Ubuntu is going to be your primary OS. **Warning: use Windows Disk Management app to resize Windows partitions** *(not gparted)*! In Windows, disable **fast boot** in the power control panel, and disable hibernation in an admin command prompt window **powercfg /h off**.

Then I'd install Ubuntu **along side of Windows**, placing root (/) on the SSD, and /home and /swap on the HDDs. Later, if you're really slick, you can setup your pictures/music/etc on a NTFS partition, and share them between Windows and Ubuntu. Predownload the correct Nvidia firmware and software files needed for your video card. Place these files on a USB flash drive and have them ready for immediate install.

Questions? Problems? Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Heynnema, I tried what you suggested and everything worked fine.  I did however try allowing third party drivers during the installation to see what took place.  The correct driver was installed I have to presume as the resolution and performance of the monitor was fine.   I expect the 'try Ubuntu' does not use the third party drivers.